# Why is CSS text-indent not working?

Tags: css

```css
.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    text-indent: 999px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #F44336;
    }
```

```html
<h1 class="logo">This is a title </h1>
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7SB2.png)

Only the first word is hidden if I assign a very large number to `text-indent` (`text-indent: 999px;`).
In this case, all words should be hidden, because `The text-indent property specifies the indentation of the first line in a text-block.`

I am not trying to hide all the text. I know the text-indent-image-replacement method. I am just curious why the code does not work properly.

Comment: what exaclt you want to do? when i play with that fiddle about indent it works fine.

Comment: @AtillaArdaAçıkgöz Just updated my code.

Comment: everything is hidden what are you looking for??

Comment: @DanyCode This is what I saw: `is a title`. Only the First word is hidden.

Comment: I did the text realy long and everything is hidden

Comment: @DanyCode I just add a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w7SB2.png Is what you saw is the same as mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your div is 200px in width. The indentation does not brake and until first space is found string is treated as one long word. After the space rest of the text appears in the box - in the second line.

You can prove I'm right by adding white-space: nowrap, so the text does not break.

Answer (score 7):

I found that if html element's css properly 'text-align' is used then text-indent doesn't work, in that case

```
text-align:unset;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip in the right direction. In my case my parent element was set with `text-align: right` so I had to add to my child element `text-align: left`.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  text-indent: 999px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: blue;
  background: red;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="logo">This is a title </h1>
```

The text indent adds that much pixels to the starting of the line and **wraps text to next lines**, that is what is happening in your case. Its pushing starting of text to `999px`. The text you see is actually pushed to lines after this.

If you want it to move out of screen use negative indent which will start the line that much pixels to the left and text magically disappears, as it starts that much pixels to the left and have to *travel* that much before it has to break to next line before hitting the right side edge.

You can also disable wrapping of text + overflow as hidden with css to get desired effect.

Comment: you and mike and user3802077 all gave the correct answer. but I can only accept one answer, so I accpet the one that answers first.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a negative value to `text-indent` to hide all your text

[Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VanFB/11/)

```
text-indent: -999px;
```

Comment: I am not trying to hide all the text. I know the text-indent-image-replacement method. I am just curious why the code does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

i think is because in the Fiddle you put the parent

```css
.parent-dev h1{
    text-indent:-999999em;
    background:url('images/thing.png');
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-dev">
<h1>Look at me, I am text.Look at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am texLook at me, I am tex</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> all words should be hidden

use 150px and you should see why only the first word is hidden.

At 999px the first line is indented, what you see is the second one.